# Email parsing: TypeError: parse() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python

I am getting the following error while calling a built-in function to parse an email in Python.

```
txt = parser.Parser.parse(fd, headersonly=False)
```

And the error i got is

```
TypeError: parse() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given).
```

Can anybody tell me the way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because `.parse()` is an instance method, not a class method.

Instead, try `Parser().parse(…)` or possibly [email.message_from_file](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_file)/[email.message_from_string](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_string).

Comment: This is almost always the problem when you get a `takes at least X arguments (Y given)` message where X and Y somehow don't make sense (like they match).

Comment: I tried email.message_from_string it was working fine.
I wanted to try the parse method.

Thanks for your answer and its working fine.:)

Comment: Cool, glad it works. To accept my answer, click the checkbox under the “number of votes” and up/down arrows on the left.

Answer (score 17):

I got the same basic error for a different reason: specifying an argument that has a default value but forgetting to give an argument that doesn't have any default value. For instance,

```
def greeting(name,root = "Hello, "):
    print root + name
greeting(root = "Good morning, ")
```

returns

```
TypeError: greeting() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)
```

The "1 given" here is the (**optional**) "root" argument but the (**required**) "name" argument was erroneously omitted.

Comment: excellent , the error message should be more clear even if somehow just looking at the signature is enough to see the error